# Several subqueries to WITH table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, with-statement

Assuming i have the following table:

```sql
create table Employee
  (
  ID                 VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
  First_Name         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  Last_Name          VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  Start_Date         DATE,
  End_Date           DATE,
  Salary             Number(8,2),
  City               VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  Description        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
  )
  ;
```

```sql
insert into employee (
ID,  First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date,                               
End_Date,                       Salary,  City,       Description)
select 21 + (level * 2) - 1,'Jason',    'Martin',  to_date('19960725','YYYYMMDD'), 
to_date ('20060725','YYYYMMDD'), 1234.56+level/3*5, 'Toronto',  'Programmer'
from dual
connect by level < 2501
;
```

When i am trying to run the following query:

```sql
with tt2 as (
select t.*, 
case when rownum = 1 then 1 when rownum = 3 then 3 else null end rfn
```

-- RFN is a example for a complex case which only assigns numbers to rows that is needed. Please don't fix on it

```
from (select id, first_name, salary from employee) t
)

select  
(select id from tt2 where rfn = 3) w
from dual
```

It returns me all of ID's that is similar to the one where rfn = 3 ( 2500 rows of 26 )

And here is explain plan

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
"Plan hash value: 2716438026"
" "
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                  | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                           |  2500 |       |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  1 |  VIEW                      |                           |  2500 | 42500 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL        | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6645_8CDDE2 |  2500 | 60000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   3 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                           |       |       |            |          |"
"|   4 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6645_8CDDE2 |       |       |            |          |"
"|   5 |    COUNT                   |                           |       |       |            |          |"
"|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | EMPLOYEE                  |  2500 | 60000 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   7 |   VIEW                     |                           |  2500 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6645_8CDDE2 |  2500 | 60000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
" "
"Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
"---------------------------------------------------"
" "
"   1 - filter(""RFN""=3)"
" "
"Note"
"-----"
"   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)"
```

**--edit--**

For instance i have table in WITH:

```
"ID"    "FIRST_NAME"    "SALARY"        "RFN"
"22"    "Jason"        1236.23           1
"24"    "Jason"        1237.89
"26"    "Jason"        1239.56           3
```

I want to select Salary of anyone with RFN = 1, giving me single number 1236.23

But i also want in the same query to select Salary of enyone with RFN = 3, 
giving me single number 1239.56.

And so on.

But. For each of this query it makes FULL_TABLE_SCAN of N rows.

```sql
with tt2 as (
select t.*, case when rownum = 1 then 1 when rownum = 3 then 3 else null end rfn
from (select id, first_name, salary from employee) t
)
select  
(select salary from tt2 where rfn = 1) w,
(select salary from tt2 where rfn = 3) w
from dual
```

Explain table:

```
('Plan hash value: 1823688231');
(' ');
('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
('| Id  | Operation                  | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |');
('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
('|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                           |  2500 |       |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|*  1 |  VIEW                      |                           |  2500 | 40000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL        | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6651_8CDDE2 |  2500 | 60000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|*  3 |  VIEW                      |                           |  2500 | 40000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL        | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6651_8CDDE2 |  2500 | 60000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|   5 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                           |       |       |            |          |');
('|   6 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6651_8CDDE2 |       |       |            |          |');
('|   7 |    COUNT                   |                           |       |       |            |          |');
('|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | EMPLOYEE                  |  2500 | 60000 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|   9 |   VIEW                     |                           |  2500 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('|  10 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6651_8CDDE2 |  2500 | 60000 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |');
('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
(' ');
('Predicate Information (identified by operation id):');
('---------------------------------------------------');
(' ');
('   1 - filter("RFN"=1)');
('   3 - filter("RFN"=3)');
(' ');
('Note');
('-----');
('   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)');
```

**--edited for more clarification--**

Expected result from :

```
"ID"    "FIRST_NAME"    "SALARY"        "RFN"
"22"    "Jason"        1236.23           1
"24"    "Jason"        1237.89
"26"    "Jason"        1239.56           3
"26"    "Jack"         1249.56           6
"26"    "Wiki"         119.56            8
```

```
salary   salary1   salary2  name  name2
1236.23  1249.56   119.56  Wiki  Jack
```

from the ~following statement:

```sql
with tt2 as (
select t.*, case when row_number() over (order by id) = 1 then 1 when row_number() over     (order by id) = 3 then 3 else null end rfn
from (select id, first_name, salary from employee) t
)
select 
(select salary from tt2 where rfn = 1) salary,
(select salary from tt2 where rfn = 6) salary1,
(select salary from tt2 where rfn = 8) salary2,
(select first_name from tt2 where rfn = 8) name,
(select first_name from tt2 where rfn = 6) name2

from dual
```

without 5 full table scans of 2500 rows

Comment: This code is very hard to follow, possibly because the meaning of it is completely obscured by the abstraction that you're using. The case statement based on rownum, which you comment as "Example only", means nothing in the context of the query that you're selecting from.  Can you explain the meaning of all of this, and what problem you're actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I am creating a temporary table in WITH. Then by CASE i assign specific different numbers to each row in this table. Than i want to select specific values from that table. By newly acquired number.

Comment: You still didn't explain what you're actually trying to do. And why doesn't ROW_NUMBER work, it's recommded over ROWNUM. Btw, the "weird reason" is not weird, it's exactly what you wrote: return the same id for all rows.

Comment: I never said i need same id's for all rows. Only one value with specific row_ID ( that is created by CASE in WITH table ) from WITH table while not getting that 2500 rows in return. Example added above.

Comment: You didn't say so, but you told Oracle in your SELECT to return this result.  Maybe you should start learning the basics of SQL first :-)

Comment: So is this a problem with there being a full table scan? That's what I infer from the edit to the question.

Comment: > You didn't say so, but you told Oracle in your SELECT to return this
> result. Maybe you should start learning the basics of SQL first :-) –
> **dnoeth** 

I should indeed. Thanks.

I should have wrote 'from dual' instead of 'from tt2'

Comment: @ David Aldridge yes. It makes full table scan to employee for each subquery.

Comment: You've completely lost me. Of course it's giving you a full table scan and you're getting every row; you're getting every row from the table. As you've said that the current answer isn't what you want (which directly contradicts your question) you're explanation of your problem is not good enough. Could you please provide the expected result from your sample data?

Comment: Got you @Fate; you're looking to pivot (should you have 4 columns in your expected results?). Do you have a defined number of `rfn`s or is it variable?

Comment: @Ben I should have approx. 20 different columns most of them will be cases. But there will be only two numbered rows in WITH table. 1 and 2. And Ben, no i am not looking for PIVOT. WITH table contains ~100 different columns and 1-8 rows. Every case in main select will choose only 1 value of specific column on specific row.

Comment: You're not looking for PIVOT,  but your expected result is a kind of pivot. Maybe simply return the needed data with IN(1,6,8) and then use the good ol' MAX(CASE...) approach instead of multiple Scalar Subqueries

Comment: @dnoeth Thing is there is a somewhat complex logic involved. Something like 'case if х = 5 and y = 7 then (select foo from tt2 where rfn = 1) if x = 5 and y = 9 then (select foo from tt2 where rfn = 2) else (select bar from tt2 where rfn = 1) end zyx' And everything like that in the main query. And that is unavoidable.

Comment: When Oracle's optimizer is not capable to materialize the result of the cte you can do that manually. If you need run this query multiple times you might once CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE and then simply INSERT/SELECT into it before you run your SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for all rows, you have to change to:

```
with tt2 as (
select t.*, case when rownum = 1 then 1 when rownum = 3 then 3 else null end rfn
from (select id, first_name, salary from employee) t
)
select salary from tt2 where rfn in (1,3)
```

But why do want this result? The ROWNUM is not deterministic without ORDER BY, it's not guaranteed to have the same order every time. You probablly need to use ROW_NUMBER like:

```
WITH tt2 AS (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn)
SELECT salary 
FROM tt2 
WHERE rn IN (1,3)
```

Comment: That is absolutely not what i want. And 'case when row_number() over (order by id) = 1 then 1 when row_number() over (order by id) = 3 then 3 else null end rfn' will not make any difference either in my case. This is a example for a complex case which only makes numbers to rows that is needed. Please don't fix on it.

Comment: The CASE WHEN will not reduce the number of rows processed. it's just more complicated for the optimizer. And you should never judge a plan for a small table, better check it for a large table, the optimizer might put more effort in that plan then.

Comment: This just an example. My main query takes ~15-30 seconds to run while WITH table in that query takes only 1.3 sec. And it had a lot more than 2.5k rows.